# Text View is flashing/blinking in my application

Tags: android, textview

We're developing a custom Android application built for a specific Android -- formerly the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 -- and I was pretty happy with the way it looked.

However, we've changed phones to the Nexus 7, and now a Text View that used to look fine blinks rapidly -- it's seizure inducing.  My application updates the text a few times a second, but that's not new and we never had this problem with the Samsung.

Has anybody experienced something similar, or otherwise have a suggestion??  My original suspicion that the Samsung had more processor power is, I'm pretty sure, incorrect.  Should I look into some of the Nexus' configuration details concerning rendering the GPU??

It's going to be annoying if have to get rid of this software feature, but I might have to if I can't improve the look.

Comment: What is the width set to - WRAP_CONTENT?  If so, are you clearing the text and then setting new text (which would make the field flatten, then re-stretch)?

Comment: The width is fixed -- set to "84sp", but that's not a bad thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a great answer, but it does work for me if I set up my code to only update the text view every other trip through the draw loop.  If anyone else has a different suggestion I'd certainly prefer to try something else, but this at least works.